When is 2 qualitatively different from 3?
I'd like to get a list of instances in mathematics where a problem with two parameters (or some parameter set to $2$) is qualitatively different from the instance of that problem with the value set to $3$.
Examples include:

Hypothesis testing, where for 2 alternatives there is an analytically computable minimax strategy (Neyman-Pearson), but for 3 or more, the minimax decision is NP-hard to compute.

Voting theory: for 2 alternatives, simple majority vote is Pareto-efficient, non-dictatorial, and satisfies independence of irrelevant alternatives (trivially). For 3 or more, we have Arrow's impossibility theorem.

Graph coloring/satisfiability: both 2-SAT and 2-COLORABILITY are in P, while 3-SAT and 3-COLORABILITY are NP-complete


If anyone has any unifying intuition for why/when 3 is qualitatively different from 2, that would be great too.

See this thread on [scicomp.se] for many examples.

$x_1^n+x_2^n=0$ vs $x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n=0$...

Something that doesn't quite fit the letter of the post, but perhaps the spirit: Kakeya sets are not too hard to understand in 2 dimensions, but become extremely difficult to understand in 3 dimensions.

Many statements about primes hold unless the prime is $2$.

I think there was a question about oddities of two some time ago, perhaps it was on math.stackexchange.

Maybe I was thinking of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573308/whats-so-special-about-characteristic-2 or of one of the many questions about "two" that are mentioned there under Linked or Related. Here on MO we have had https://mathoverflow.net/questions/915/is-there-a-high-concept-explanation-for-why-characteristic-2-is-special

I'd like to see an answer to the why question.

For almost all answers, it is rather "2" vs "$n\ge 3$".

@YCor This also holds for the examples of the OP. Often counting $1,2,3,\infty$ makes sense.

Related: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3344266/11323 about 3 vs 4

I wonder how many of these are explained by the fact that when you have 2 possibilities, eliminating one possibility is the same thing as finding the answer, but when you have 3 or more possibilities, those are not the same thing.

Many examples are of the form “for $n \geq 2$ things are simple; for $n \geq 3$ they’re complicated”  (e.g. @BenJohnsrude’s comment of Kakeya sets, or Wojowu’s answer on free lattices).  These seem much less notable or interesting than examples where the complexity of the problem is decreasing or non-monotonic in $n$ — where $n = 3$ is simple (and maybe also $n \geq 3$) but $n=2$ is complicated.

There is the so-called Hartshorne-Serre correspondence between codimension $2$ smooth subvarieties $Y \subset X$ (with some additional condition) of a smooth algebraic variety $X$ and certain rank $2$ vector bundles on $X$. There is no general analogue of Serre's construction in codimension $3$ or more. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136797/hartshorne-serres-correspondence-in-higher-codimension

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47333/examples-of-collapsing-hierarchies some answers fit here.

Random walks in 2 dimensions are recurrent whereas in higher dimensions random walks are not. And there is a wonderful colloquialism by Shizuo Kakutani to remember this: “A drunk man will find his way home but a drunk bird may get lost forever.”

Stein's paradox is a corollary of this result

@Cyan: How do you see Stein’s paradox as coming from these?

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Wikipedia says "An alternative proof [of Stein's example] is due to Larry Brown: he proved that the ordinary estimator for an $n$-dimensional multivariate normal mean vector is admissible if and only if the $n$-dimensional Brownian motion is recurrent" pointing at Brown, L. D. (1971). "Admissible Estimators, Recurrent Diffusions, and Insoluble Boundary Value Problems". The Annals of Mathematical Statistics. 42 (3): 855–903. doi:10.1214/aoms/1177693318 . ISSN 0003-4851.

Thanks for the wonderful quote by Kakutani: I have finally solved the puzzling mystery on the absence of drunk birds in our environnement.

Fermat's last theorem states that there are no non-trivial integer solutions to $x^n+y^n=z^n$ for $n=3$ (or in fact any $n\geq 3$), but there are of course many Pythagorean triples that give solutions for $n=2$.

This was commented by @JPMcCarthy.

@LSpice not quite (look again) but in the same spirit.

@JPMcCarthy, ah, right, my apologies to the poster of the answer.

@LSpice no worries, and it is close in spirit indeed.

Infinitely many regular polygons in dimension 2, five regular polyhedra in dimension 3.

2:infinity.
3:5.
4:6.
5+:3.

@Sparr And 0:1, 1:1.

https://oeis.org/A060296

N-body problems are another; the 2-body case is simple, the 3-body case is intractable.

This is certainly true in general, but it's interesting to note that even the 2-body case can be hard. The prime example being general relativity.

@eddyardonne The two-body problem is not solvable even in special relativity.

In integrable systems the 3-body case is tractable, but still very different from the (simple) 2-body case. In quantum-integrable systems, the 3-body case is related to the (quantum) Yang--Baxter equation. It is a gateway to the n-body case due to 'factorised scattering'.

It is relatively easy to "divide by 2" without choice, but it is very hard to "divide by 3".

There's actually a simpler and more explicit way than given in that paper, given in the confusingly named paper "Division by Four": https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01402

Actually, it’s not so simple: https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.11634

@HarryAltman -  Doyle and Qiu (2015) was "Division by four" because the link in Keith's answer was Doyle and Conway (1994) "Division by three"

I'm aware of the reason for the title; that doesn't change the fact that the title is misleading.

As mentioned in another answer, free lattice on $2$ generators is finite, while a free lattice on $3$ generators is infinite.
Even more impressively though, a free complete lattice on $2$ elements is finite (it simply coincides with the free lattice) while a free complete lattice on $3$ elements does not exist.

On the other hand, the free modular lattice on 3 generators is finite (Dedekind) but for greater than 3 generators is infinite (Birkhoff).

There exist plenty of continuous maps $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ whose largest periodic cycle has length $2$, but no such maps whose largest cycle has length $3$. (This is a consequence of Sharkovskii's theorem.)

Lots of questions about tensors are easy when the order of the tensor is 2 (i.e., when it can be thought of as a matrix), but are NP-hard when the order of the tensor is 3 or higher. Examples include rank and spectral norm.

Every group in which every non-identity element has order 2 is abelian.

Math Stackexchange question whose answers explain why this is no true for $3$ instead of $2$ (for those whose knowledge of basic group theory is as rusty as mine).

Ando's theorem: any pair of commuting contractions on a Hilbert space can be dilated to a pair of commuting unitaries. This fails for three commuting contractions.

Due to the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem, continuous dynamical systems can not be chaotic in two dimensions, while they can in three dimensions.

In a three or higher dimensional Euclidian space, the infinitesimal conformal transformations generate a finite dimensional Lie algebra, while in two dimensional Euclidian space, it is an infinite dimensional Lie algebra.

There exists a finitely additive isometry invariant measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ extending the Lebesgue measure for $1 \leq n \leq 2$, but not for $n \geq 3$.

$SL_3(\mathbb R)$ and $SL_3(\mathbb Z)$ exhibit Kazhdan's property (T).  $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ and $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ do not.

Complex numbers exist only in dimension 2. That is the only multiplication laws on $R^n$ which satisfy all field axioms exist for $n=1$ (real numbers) and $n=2$ (complex numbers).

The automorphism group of $k[x_1,x_2]$ (the polynomial ring in two variables over a field $k$) is pretty well understood classically, but very little is known about the automorphism group of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ for $n\geq 3$: see "The Tame and the Wild Automorphisms of Polynomial Rings in Three Variables," by Shestakov–Umirbaev.  See also the Wikipedia page for the related problem on the ring of rational functions.

One can decide if a Diophantine equation of degree $d=2$ (and as many variables as you want) admits a solution over $\mathbb Z$ (Siegel 1972) or $\mathbb N$ (Grunewald and Segal 2006). The same question is wide open in degree $d=3$, and known to be undecidable in degree $d\ge 4$.

This is quantitative rather than qualitative, but it's so huge that it fits, perhaps:
TREE(2) vs TREE(3)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem#TREE_function

Let $G$ be a finite group. If the order of $G$ is not divisible by 2, then $G$ is solvable; if it is not divisible by 3, then no such conclusion can be drawn.

Although there still aren't ‘many’, in some sense, possible non-cyclic composition factors of prime-to-$3$ groups. (I asked a recent MSE question about this.)

If $n$ is finite, then the number of clones on an $n$-element set is countable if $n\leq 2$ and has size continuum if $n\geq 3$.

What's a clone on a set?

@Dirk: A "clone" is a "closed set of operations". ( nlab entry: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/clone   Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(algebra) )

For a subset $A$ of a (not necessarily abelian) group $G$, define the iterated product set
$$A^n=\{a_1\cdots a_n \mid a_1,\ldots,a_n\in A\}.$$
Good control on the size of $A^3$ (small tripling of $A$) is enough to give control on the size of $A^n$:
$$|A^3|\leq K|A|\implies |A^n|\leq K^{n-2}|A|\text{ for every }n\geq 3.$$
On the other hand, if one only knows $|A^2|\leq K|A|$ (small doubling of $A$), such strong bounds are (very) false. One example (copied from Example 2.5.2 in Tointon's Approximate Groups) is as follows: let $H$ be any finite group, let $G$ be the free product of $H$ with an infinite cyclic group generated by some element $x$. Let $A=H\cup\{x\}$. Then
$$|A^2|=|H\cup xH\cup Hx\cup \{x^2\}|=3|H|+1<3|A|,$$
while
$$|A^3|\geq|H\cup xH\cup Hx\cup HxH|=1+2|H|+|H|^2=|A|^2$$
is much larger than $|A|$.

Graph theory
Regular graphs of degree $2$ are just cycles (if connected), but regular graphs of degree $3$ are in some sense already as complicated as it can get.
Graphs of chromatic number $2$ behave so differently from chromatic number $\ge 3$ that they got a special name: bipartite graphs. OP already mentioned graph coloring, but I want to emphasize that the distinction goes much deeper and bipartite is not always the easy case. For example, the asymptotics of extremal edge numbers follows from the Erdős–Stone theorem when forbidding non-bipartite sub-graphs, but is mostly unknown when forbidding bipartite sub-graphs.
$r$-uniform hypergraphs for $r=2$ are just good old graphs and are much simpler objects than for $r\ge 3$.

"graphs of degree 3 are in some sense already as complicated as it can get." Can that be made precise? Something to do with edge contractions and homeomorphisms, perhaps?

@user76284 Yes, every (finite) graph is a minor of a 3-regular graph.

An $n$-generated free lattice is finite if $n\leq 2$ and infinite if $n\geq 3$.

If we say that integer partitions correspond to $n=1$, plane partitions to $n=2$ and solid partitions to $n=3$, then the cases $n=1,2$ are special in the sense that a simple generating function is known, while for $n\geq3$ this is not the case.

The Ising model is NP-complete for $d \geq 3$ but not $d \leq 2$.
The Ising Model Is NP-Complete. SIAM News, Volume 33, Number 6:

The three-dimensional spin glass model for the standard square lattice [is] NP-complete. More precisely, for the three-dimensional result, Barahona showed that a graph-theoretic problem known to be NP-complete—the task of finding a maximum set of independent edges (i.e., with no vertices in common) in a graph for which each vertex has degree 3—can be reduced to the problem of finding a ground state for the three-value coupling constant ($J_{ij}$ = –1, 0, or 1) on a cubic grid.


In fact there are a lot of exactly solvable models in 2 dimensions that fail to be exactly solvable in higher dimensions. This is related to the fact that Kasteleyn's theorem for planar graphs has no higher-dimensional analogue.

The Banach-Tarski paradox holds in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but fails in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Isn't this the same as this earlier answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/482100/9652, but in a fancier language?

There's similar paradoxes for subsets of the circle

The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2^{n-2}\mathbb{Z}$ and is non-cyclic whenever $n \ge 3$. The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}/3^n \mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic of order $\phi(3^n) = 2 \times 3^{n-1}$.

Just to make explicit a qualitative difference between two and three that is implicit here, the multiplicative group modulo $2^2$ is cyclic, but the multiplicative group modulo $2^3$ is not.

The wave equation
$$\partial_t^2u=\Delta_xu$$
exhibits different behaviour in space dimension $2$ and $3$ (more generally in even and odd space dimensions). The simplest is $d=3$ (!), where the fundamental solution (initial data $u(0,\cdot)\equiv0$ and $\partial_tu(0\cdot)\delta_0$, the Dirac mass) has a lacuna: it vanishes identically away from the light cone $\|x\|=|t|$. This implies the Huyghens principle. If instead $d=2$, then the fundamental solution is supported by the solid cone $\|x\|\le|t|$, and the Huyghens principle fails.

The number $c_n$ of closed walks on $\mathbb Z^d$ of length $2n$ has a nice formula for $d=1,2$ (we have $c_n={2n\choose n}$ in dimension $d=1$, and $c_n={2n\choose n}^2$ in dimension $d=2$). Formulas for $d\ge 3$ are necessarily much worse, with at least a sum (see https://oeis.org/A002896).
This is linked to the fact that $[-1,1]^d$ is self-dual for $d=1,2$, but not for $d\ge 3$.

Sort of similar to this is the fact that the sequence $a^d_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^d$ (sum of $d$th powers of $n$th row of Pascal's triangle) has a nice formula in the case of $d=1,2$ ($a^1_n = 2^n$, $a^2_n = \binom{2n}{n}$), but for $d \geq 3$ has no nice formula (e.g. I believe the corresponding generating function is not algebraic).

In this case, it is algebraic for $d=1$, and D-finite (but not algebraic) for all $d\ge 2$.

What does self-dual mean here?

Just isomorphic to its dual as an abstract polytope, hypercube and hyperoctahedron coincide in dimension $d=1,2$.

The congruence subgroup problem has a positive answer for $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ for $n\geq 3$ - every finite index subgroup contains a subgroup of the form $\{A\mid A\equiv I_n\pmod N\}$ for some $N$.
For $n=2$, this is no longer the case - $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ has many non-congruence finite index subgroups, in fact most (in asymptotic sense) of them are.

General relativity is topological for $\leq 2$ spatial dimensions.
Quantum gravity in 2 + 1 dimensions: The case of a closed universe:

A (2 + 1)-dimensional spacetime has no local degrees of freedom: There
are no gravitational waves in the classical theory, and no propagating gravitons in the quantum theory.


I was going to mention quantum gravity but you beat me to it!

Anyons exist in 2 dimensions, but not higher dimensions (due to the spin-statistics theorem).
This is connected to the fact that braid groups are trivial in higher dimensions.

A subtle case where $3$ as the parameter gives a simpler result than $2$:
Consider the infinite product
$$\prod\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{n^k-1}{n^k+1},$$
which converges for all $k>1$. For $k=3$ we can use the factorizations of $a^3\pm b^3$ to telescope the product in terms of rational functions and thus guarantee a rational value, namely $2/3$. For $k=2$ a telescoping is still possible but more complicated, requiring the use of the gamma function and identities involving it to attain the result $\pi/{\sinh(\pi)}$.

Quadratic equations satisfy the Hasse principle while cubic equations don't.

Here is another example with Gaussian mixture models (GMMs). The landscape of loss for learning a mixture of 2 Gaussians seems to have no bad local optima but that is not the case for a mixture of 3 or more: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00978

Can one find a net of functions $(f_i)$ in the Fourier algebra of ${\rm SL}_n({\bf Z})$ such that the "amplified net" $(f_i \otimes 1)$, with $1$ denoting the constant function on ${\rm SU}(2)$, acts as an approximate identity for the Fourier algebra of ${\rm SL}_n({\bf Z})\times {\rm SU}(2)$?
The answer is positive for $n=2$ (follows from Haagerup's proof that ${\rm SL}_2({\bf Z})$ is "weakly amenable") but negative for all $n\geq 3$ (this is the statement that for such $n$, ${\rm SL}_n({\bf Z})$ does not have AP, proved by V. Lafforgue and M. de la Salle).

If all the roots of a (real, irreducible) quadratic are real, then they can be expressed in terms of real radicals. If all the roots of a (real, irreducible) cubic are real, then they can't be expressed in terms of real radicals.

On mobile now, but Gleason’s theorem needs to be on here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleason%27s_theorem .

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a countable complete theory with exactly $n$ models (up to isomorphism) of cardinality $\aleph_0$, if and only if $n \neq 2$.
This is known as "Vaught's never 2 theorem".
Related reading: spectrum of a theory, Vaught conjecture.

In reverse mathematics, some theorems that are weaker than $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ become equivalent to $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ by increasing a $2$ occurring in the statement to $3$.
An example is the infinite Ramsey theorem with finite dimension and arbitrarily many colors. Let $\mathrm R^n$ be the infinite Ramsey theorem for functions $f:\mathbb N^n\to\mathbb N$. Then $\mathsf{WKL}_0+\mathrm R^2$ is $\Pi^1_1$-conservative over $\mathsf B\Sigma^0_3$ (Slaman, Yokoyama, "The strength of Ramsey's theorem for pairs and arbitrarily many colors", 2018), in particular the theory $\mathsf{RCA}_0+\mathrm R^2$ cannot prove $\mathsf B\Sigma^0_4$, but $\mathrm R^2$ is provable in $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, so $\mathrm R^2$ must be strictly weaker than $\mathsf{ACA}_0$. However, $\mathrm R^3$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ (theorem III.7.6 of Simpson's Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic).
I remember hearing somewhere that strengthening weak Kőnig's lemma to include trees with labels from $\{0,1,2\}$ instead of labels from $\{0,1\}$ gives a statement equivalent to $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, but I am not able to find a source.

Two-variable logic is decidable. Three-variable logic is undecidable.
For a close study of this boundary, see An excursion to the border of decidability: between two- and three-variable logic by Fiuk and Kieroński.

Discrete spheres: in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ every element has a unique antipodal point at distance $n$. In $\mathbb{F}_3^n$ every element is distance $n$ from exactly $2^n$ points, so exponentially many.
Smooth spheres: In the $2$-sphere, the surface area between two lines of longitude depends only on the difference in height, and so is proportional to the area of the part of the enclosing cylinder. (As was known to Euclid.) In the $3$-sphere, the area is biggest at the equator, and smallest at the poles; the density function is $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ for $-1 \le z \le 1$.

The Jordan–Schönflies theorem does not hold for 3 dimensions: there is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ that is homeomorphic to the 3-ball but its exterior is not simply connected. However, such analogous examples do not exist in 2D.

A two-player zero-sum game is easy to solve in polynomial time. It's essentially a convex optimization problem.
A three-player zero-sum game is PPAD-hard to solve, i.e. just as difficult as a general game and believed to require superpolynomial time. It's essentially a fixed-point problem, which is harder in general than convex optimization.

Rationality of (sufficiently general) smooth hypersurfaces in projective space of degree $2$ (known in all dimensions) versus degree $3$ (open in all except a few dimensions).

Here is an example I encountered in my research:
Let $A=(a_{n, m})$ be an $N\times M$ matrix such that for all $n$ there exists $k=k(n)$ such that $a_{n,m}=0$ if $m\neq k, k+1$, that is in every row we have at most two non-zero numbers and they go one after the other, and assume that we want to know if $A$ is injective, that is whether there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Av=0$. Then it is not terribly difficult to convince yourself that this can be done by only looking at which elements of the matrix $A$ are non-zero and which pairs of rows of $A$ are linearly independent and do some fairly simple combinatorics depending on this.
However, if we say that $a_{n, m}=0$ if $m\neq k, k+1, k+2$, that is if we allow for 3 consecutive non-zero elements, then the problem becomes at least as hard as the one of determining whether the Jacobi matrix is non-singular which is a subject of dozens of books and hundredths of papers, and in particular is a very difficult problem to approach analytically.

did you mean "hundreds" or actually "hundredths"?

I do mean that, thank you @mathworker21

@mathworker21, re, I love the opportunity for sneaky precision. "My work is so influential that it has been cited hundredths of times!"

@LSpice ha! ${}{}{}$

Geometric theory and abstract algebra
Bisecting an angle can be accomplished with ruler and compass.
Trisecting an angle cannot be accomplished with ruler and compass.

Matrix theory
It is possible to construct $2$-by-$2$ Hadamard matrices.
It is impossible to construct $3$-by-$3$ Hadamard matrices.
It is possible to construct $2$-by-$2$ conference matrices.
It is impossible to construct $3$-by-$3$ conference matrices.

These examples from matrix theory are true... but I think the spirit of the question was something like "$n = 2$ versus $n \geq 3$". The Hadamard matrix example, for example, rubs me the wrong way because it's kind of like saying "$n = 2$ is even, whereas $n = 3$ is not".

Re Geometric theory: the duplication of a square (described in Plato's Meno) is easy.  But the duplication of a cube is not.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ be a field. Consider the group algebra $K[G]$, and for $k\in \{2,3\}$ look for a largest linear subspace $X\subset K[G]$ for which $X^k=0$ (in the sense that $x_1x_2\ldots x_k=0$ for all $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ in $X$).
Theorem-2. For $k=2$, ${\rm codim}\, X\geqslant |G|/2$.
Proof. The bilinear form $(x,y)\to [e]xy$ (where $x,y\in K[G]$ and $[e]x$ means the coefficient of $e$ in the expansion of $x\in K[G]$ as a linear combination of elements of $G$) is non-degenerated, thus, if two subspaces (in our situation both subspaces are $X$) are orthogonal, the sum of their codimensions is not less than $|G|$.
Theorem-3. For $k=3$, it may appear that ${\rm codim}\, X<|G|^{0.99}$ for arbitrarily large $|G|$.
Proof. Say, for $G=C_2^n$, where $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order 2, denote the generator of $i$-th $C_2$ by $g_i$, and take for $X$ the span of elements $\prod_{i\in I} (g_i-e)$, where $I\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $|I|>n/3$. Since $(g_i-e)^2=0$ for all $i$, by pigeonhole principle we get $X^3=0$, and the codimension of $X$ is $\sum_{k\leqslant n/3} {n\choose k}<2^{0.92 n}$ by the entropy bound for binomial distribution.
This example may seem artificial, but actually the minimal codimension of the subspace with zero cube is an upper bound for many natural combinatorial characteristics of the group, like (the half of) the maximal size of a set without progressions of length 3, it is a group algebra view of the breakthrough paper by Croot--Lev--Pach.

The group cohomology ring of $H^*(\mathbb{Z}/p;\mathbb{F}_p)$ is a polynomial ring when $p=2$, and a tensor product of a polynomial ring with an exterior algebra, when $p>2$. This often leads to differences so that the case of $p=2$ must be treated separately.

Mutual information of two random variables is non-negative and I daresay well understood. Mutual information of three or more random variables can be negative, and is monstrously unintuitive.

@Turbo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_information

Applying Newton's method to find roots of degree 2 polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ would produce two nice smooth basins of attraction. Doing the same for a polynomial of degree 3 would produce three fractal sets.
There's a very nice video on that:
https://youtu.be/-RdOwhmqP5s?si=L4078Oc7t0Rl4E88

There's an important example from algorithmic complexity theory.
The Boolean satisfiability problem (SAT) consists,
given $n$ Boolean variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$,
in asking whether we can assign truth values to these variables
in a way that makes a given Boolean expression true,
where the expression can use conjunction
($\wedge$, "and"), disjunction ($\vee$, "or"), and negation ($\neg$).
For example, the expression
$$(x_1 \wedge \neg x_2) \vee (x_2 \wedge x_3)$$
is satisfiable:
setting $x_1 = \top$, $x_2 = \bot$, $x_3 = \top$ makes it true
(where $\top$ and $\bot$ denote true and false respectively).
Note that variables can appear multiple times in the expression,
as $x_2$ does above.
In contrast, the expression
$$x_1 \wedge \neg x_1$$
is not satisfiable,
as no truth value for $x_1$ can make this true.
We can consider restricted versions of SAT.
The 2-SAT problem only considers expressions
formed by taking the conjunction of clauses,
where each clause is the disjunction
of two (possibly negated) variables.
For example:
$$(x_1 \vee x_2) \wedge (\neg x_1 \vee x_3) \wedge (x_2 \vee \neg x_3).$$
Similarly, 3-SAT restricts to expressions
where each clause is the disjunction
of three (possibly negated) variables, for example:
$$(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee x_3) \wedge (\neg x_1 \vee x_2 \vee \neg x_4) \wedge (x_2 \vee x_3 \vee x_4).$$
These two problems, while syntactically similar,
have fundamentally different relationships to the SAT problem.
Through a straightforward but clever construction,
any SAT instance can be transformed into an equivalent 3-SAT instance
by introducing auxiliary variables -- this is called a reduction.
For example, the clause $(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee x_3 \vee x_4)$
can be replaced by $(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee y) \wedge (x_3 \vee x_4 \vee \neg y)$
where $y$ is a new auxiliary variable.
No such reduction to 2-SAT exists in general.
This is already a big difference between 2 and 3,
but it actually goes a lot deeper.
We can algorithmically solve any 2-SAT instance in linear time
by reducing the problem to finding
the strongly connected components of a directed graph,
making 2-SAT a problem of the class P, i.e.,
of problems that can be algorithmically solved in polynomial time.
In contrast, 3-SAT is NP-complete.
Cook's theorem (1971) showed that every problem in NP can be reduced to SAT,
and the reduction from SAT to 3-SAT then implies that 3-SAT is also NP-complete.
Under the assumption that P≠NP,
this means that while 2-SAT can be solved efficiently,
no polynomial-time algorithm can solve 3-SAT in general.

A finite cell complex of cohomological dimension (including twisted cohomology) $n>2$, is homotopy equivalent to a finite cell complex of dimension $n$.  It is unknown if this is true for $n=2$.

There is no infinite squarefree word on a binary alphabet, but there is one on an $n$-ary alphabet for $n>2$.

Hilbert scheme of points on a smooth surface is irreducible. But for dimension greater than two, these are completely wild.

$0/1$ square matrix permanent modulo $2$ is in polynomial time but for modulo $3$ it is not.

$\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\}$ is simply connected for $d\ge 3$, but not for $d=2$.

It's also simply connected for $d < 2$, at least if you allow an empty or disconnected space to be so.

@LSpice I don't allow that, sorry. :-)

$p = 2$ is often an exception in number theory to statements about primes $p$. One of the most basic and yet nontrivial examples of this phenomenon is the primitive root theorem:
For all primes $p$, there exists a primitive root mod $p^k$ for all nonnegative integers $k$ if and only if $p >2$. Moreover, for $p = 2$, there exists a primitive root mod $p^k$ if and only if $k \leq 2$.  More generally, for all positive integers $m$, there exists a primitive root mod $m$ if and only if $m = p^k$, $m = 2p^k$, or $m = 4$ for some prime $p > 2$ and some nonnegative integer $k$.  Thus, such an $m$ can have at most two distinct prime factors, where the second prime factor can only be $2$!

$a^n b^n$ is context-free. $a^n b^n c^n$ isn't.

If you have two matroids $M_1,M_2$ with rank functions $r_1,r_2$ on the same ground set $E$, the collection $M_1\cap M_2$ of subsets of $E$ which are independent in both $M_1$ and $M_2$ is not, in general, a matroid. However, there exists a minimax formula $$\max_{A\subset M_1\cap M_2} |A|=\min_{E=E_1\sqcup E_2} r_1(E_1)+r_2(E_2)$$ It leads to a polynomial algorithm to find the largest size of a set in $M_1\cap M_2$.
For 3 matroids, no formula, and the analogous problem becomes NP-hard.

Application of the inverse spectral transform (IST) to the Korteweg-deVries and other non-linear partial differential equations in 2 dimensions (one space and one time) has been worked out in detail.
But 3 dimensional examples (two spatial dimensions) are much more scarce. The known examples (e.g. Kadomtsev–Petviashvili (KP) equation) have been described as "one and a half" dimensional problems, since the "soliton" solutions only involve two plane solitons interacting obliquely.

In dimension 2, every centrally symmetric convex polygon is a zonotope (Minkowski sum of segments). Equivalent reformulations:
$\bullet$ every 2-dimensional Banach space is a subspace of $L^1$;
$\bullet$ if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are vectors on the plane, $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ are real numbers and $\sum c_i|f(x_i)|\geqslant 0$ for every linear functional $f$, then $\sum c_i \|x_i\|\geqslant 0$ for every norm.
Not true in higher dimensions: an octahedron is not a sum of segments.

Weak $n$-categories (or even groupoids) are equivalent to strict $n$-categories for $n \leq 2$ but not for $n \geq 3$. This famously tripped Kapranov and Voedvosky, and the counterexample is due to Simpson.

There are quite a few examples like this from quantum information theory (beyond the basic fact that 2-tensors are "easy" and 3-tensors are "hard", which I already mentioned in another answer). Here are a couple:

A big problem in the field is, given a density matrix (mixed state) acting on $\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n$, how can we determine whether or not it is separable? It turns out this problem is easy if $n = 2$: just compute the partial transpose and then compute eigenvalues (in particular, it's polynomial-time and just makes use of "standard" linear algebra tricks). By contrast, when $n \geq 3$, it is known that the set of separable states is not semidefinite representable (loosely: it's not possible to use "standard" linear algebra tricks to determine separability).
How well can you distinguish two quantum states? If there are $n = 2$ states, there's an explicit formula for the maximum probability of distinguishing the states, and the measurements you should perform to distinguish them as well as possible come from eigenstuff (see Nielsen and Chuang's book, for example, or basically any book on quantum information theory). By contrast, when there are $n \geq 3$ states, there is a semidefinite program that can compute the optimal distinguishing probability and the optimal measurements, but there is no known explicit/closed-form formula for it (and as far as I know, it's expected that no closed-form-ish formula exists).


Let there be $k$ square matrices, $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_k : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, let $f$ be the monoid morphism $\{1, 2, \dots, k\}^* \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ generated by $f(i) = A_i$ for $1 \le i \le k$ (considering concatenations of strings and multiplication of matrices), and consider $g(w) = \operatorname{Tr}(f(w))$. $g$ is always unchanged by rotations of the string, but for $k=n=2$ it's also unchanged by reversing $w$. This doesn't hold when increasing either $n$ or $k$ to 3 (or more).

Two Variables Are Not Enough:

Let n be the smallest integer such that every closed lambda term beta converts to one with at most n bound variables. We show that n = 3.


A cardinal $\kappa$ is regular iff $\forall a (\lvert a\rvert < \kappa \land (\forall b \in a) (\lvert b\rvert < \kappa) \to \lvert\bigcup a\rvert < \kappa)$.
That is, every union of fewer than $\kappa$ sets smaller than $\kappa$ is smaller than $\kappa$.
The finite regular cardinals are exactly 0, 1, and 2.

A 2-input gate cannot be universal for reversible computing.
A 3-input gate can. For example, the Fredkin (CSWAP) gate or Toffoli (CCNOT) gate.

The Bethe lattice (infinite symmetric tree) grows exponentially for degree $\geq 3$ and at most linearly for $\leq 2$.

Equivalence relations with at most two classes on a fixed set $E$ have a natural group-structure (identify
them with the quotient group formed by maps from $E$ into $\{\pm 1\}$ modulo constant maps (the product is
multiplication of function)). No natural product exists
for equivalence relations with more than two classes.

Every ideal in a polynomial ring is isomorphic (after potentially adding variables) to a trinomial ideal (i.e., one generated by trinomials). But binomial ideals are very special. See the classic paper "Binomial Ideals" by Eisenbud and Sturmfels (https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9401001).

Only for $m=2$, $\sum_{i=1}^mx^{2n+1}_k$ is always divisible by $\sum_{i=1}^mx_k$. Indeed,
$$x+y | x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1}, n \in \mathbb N.$$
